# Mount a volume while using a docker container in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, docker-volume, azure-container-service

I've deployed a `Web App` on Azure and use a Docker Container from the public registry (my own image) to host my website. But users can upload pictures and data is stored in json-files on the server. Of course I want to write these files to a mounted volume outside of the container. So that I can redeploy an update version of my website without losing data.

Is that possible with Web Apps? Or do I need to move on to an Ubuntu VM with Docker on Azure? What I like about the webapps is I don't have to worry about managing the VM and only care about my container.

Comment: Do you use `Web app on Linux` or others?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Yes, I do (or: did). TBH: I already moved over to another cloud provider.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, `Web app on Linux` does not support mount a volume. What is the cloud provider that you use now? You could select Docker on Ubuntu VM. You could mount a Azure File share as a volume.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT But that was not what I want. I don't want to maintain a VM when the only thing I care about is the docker container.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I moved over to the Google Cloud Engine with Kubernetes which let me mount to a persistent provider.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at it. I work on Azure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This blog post is a great start and understanding Azure's strategy regarding volume mounting (*ASL == App Services on 
 Linux; ASW=App Services on Windows*):

> ... However, in this case, we would like to leverage the regular App Service Filesystem, so we can interact with the application using FTP. When a container is deployed, ASL mounts the equivalent of D:\home path on ASW to /home (using volume mount in Docker). Now when that happens, it is up to your container to map the corresponding paths into the application. In order to understand how this works more closely, take a look at the official Dockerfile used in PHP7 container on ASL.

https://hajekj.net/2016/12/25/building-custom-docker-images-for-use-in-app-service-on-linux/

Comment: @riezebosch, did you have any success seeing files in your containers /home directory appear in the Azure filesystem?  Looking in Kudu, I don't see my files appearing there.  I have a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212556/how-to-mount-azure-app-service-storage-in-jenkins-docker-container

Comment: Didn't look further into it.

Comment: Do you know of an artile with the same information but for windows?