# How to mount Azure App Service storage in Jenkins Docker Container?

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to host Jenkins in a Docker container in the Azure App Service.  This means it's 'linux' hosting.

By default the jenkins/jenkins-2.110-alpine Docker [image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine) stores its data in the /var/jenkins_home folder in the container.  I want this data/config persisted to Azure persistent storage so that it's persisted across container restarts.

I've read [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#PersistHome) and [blogs](https://hajekj.net/2016/12/25/building-custom-docker-images-for-use-in-app-service-on-linux/) stating that you can have container data persisted if it's stored in the /home folder.

So I've customized the Jenkins Dockerfile to look like this...

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.110-alpine

USER root
RUN mkdir /home/jenkins
RUN ln -s /var/jenkins_home /home/jenkins
USER jenkins
```

However, when I deploy to Azure App Service I don't see the file in my /home folder (looking in Kudu console).  The app starts just fine, but I lose all of my data when I restart my container.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @anshoewe have you found the answer to that question?

Comment: Did you set the environment variable WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true in Application Settings?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected because you only persist a symlink (`ln -s /var/jenkins_home /home/jenkins`) on the Azure host. All the files physically exist inside the container.
To do this, you have to actually change Jenkins configuration to store all data in `/home/jenkins` which you have already created in your `Dockerfile` above.

A quick search for [Jenkins data folder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) suggests that you set the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` to your directory.
In your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV JENKINS_HOME /home/jenkins
```